# Pheanstalk responds BAD_FORMAT

Tags: php, beanstalkd, pheanstalk

While using Pheanstalk and Beanstalkd I get this error.

```
Pheanstalk\Exception\ServerBadFormatException
BAD_FORMAT in response to 'put 1024 0 18446744073709551615 363'
```

Beanstalkd is running and I can access it from the terminal.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The 64 bit versions of PHP sets `PHP_INT_MAX` as 9223372036854775807.

18446744073709551615 is bigger....

From quick calculations, 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 appears to be well over 292 billion years.